# Java asterisk triangle using user data - for loop

Tags: java

I want to create a triangle in java with the user input, by default the triangle is `base=2 height = 1` so if I print this triangle should be something like this:

```
*

**
```

now how about if the customer inputs base= 5 and height=10?

I have this method, but I'm not sure which variable to use on the loop:

```
    String triangle= "";

    for (int i = 0; i < triangleArea(); i++){
        triangle= triangle+ "*";
        System.out.println(triangulo);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you need to decide what to do if the * is not precisely in the middle of a character location. I mean, what if it is exactly in between?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are doing geometry???
Try this:

```
int b= 5;
int h= 10;
//area of right triangle
int area = (b*h)/2;

for (int i = 0; i < area; i++){
  for(int x = 0; x <= i; x++){
      System.out.print("*");        
  }
System.out.println("");
}
```